# Iterators for built-in containers

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, containers

From my understanding so far, you can easily create an iterator for a *user-defined* object by simply defining **both** the `__iter__` method and the `__next__` method for it. That's pretty intuitive to understand.

I also get it that you can manually build an iterator for any *built-in* container by simply calling the `iter()` method on that container.

Using basically any container as an example, what I don't understand is why they don't define a `__next__` method for themselves. Instead, when calling the `iter` method on a container (ergo, `<container>.__iter__`) it returns a new object of type `<container_type>_iterator` and not the container itself.

---

So finally, the question is, why do container objects delegate their `iterator` functionality to separate `<type>_iterator` objects instead of defining it themselves?

Comment: Note that you can do the same for your own types; `__iter__` must return an iterator, but *that doesn't have to be the instance itself*.

Comment: Yup, I've got that. Just couldn't see the (now **clear**) logic behind the creation of separate iterator objects for containers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the container was its own iterator (e.g. provided a `__next__` method), you could only iterate over it *in one place*. You could not have independent iterators. Each call to `__next__` would give the next value in the container and you'd not be able to go back to the first value; you have in effect a generator that could only ever yield the values in the container just the once.

By creating separate iterators for a given container, you can iterate independently:

```
>>> lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> it1 = iter(lst)
>>> it2 = iter(lst)
>>> next(it1)
'foo'
>>> next(it2)
'foo'
>>> list(it1)
['bar', 'baz']
>>> next(it2)
'bar'
```